# Azure Powershell DevOps Task has issues talking to Azure China

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-china

I wrote a bunch of Azure Powershell scripts which have all been working just fine against Azure proper.  I then modified the subscription to be our Azure China subscription and Azure commands are failing 50% of the time.  I have simplified my entire pipeline down to a single Stage with a single Azure Powershell script.  I have specified my Azure China subscription and have an inline script with the following contents: "Get-AzureService"

50% of the time the script fails with the following error:
2019-08-08T22:12:51.3777403Z ##[error]An error occurred while sending the request.

I ran the job 8 times and every other time it failed.  The 2nd, 4th, 6th and 8th time I ran it, I got the correct output which is all the azure services deployed in Azure China.

My azure classic service connection is setup with a management certificate and obviously the connection works since I do get the correct output 50% of the time.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Set the value of pipeline variable "debug" to "true", so that you can get very detailed debug information. You may append it later or find the cause from it yourself.

Comment: I added the debug variable and the output was identical.  Just "An error occurred while sending the request"

Comment: I did explicitly add a -Verbose flag on the Get-AzureService command and it succeeded 3 times in a row for the first time but then failed on the next run, with no additional logging.